# debugging SharePoint solution

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there any reason why deploying solution would not deploy the solution?

Adding solution 'Booking.wsp'...
 Deploying solution 'Booking.wsp'..

When I go to Central admin I see the booking.wsp and I can manually deploy the solution. Any reason why is not deploying. no errors are thrown either.

Answer (score 0):

- run vs as admin and make sure you belong to wss_admin_wpg
- make sure you have the right url under siteurl of the project (F4)
- check the output tab for eventual deployment errors
- make sure you are admin on the site you are deploying to
- restart sptimer and spadmin services and remove the solution before retrying
- finally, check your deployment actions in the project settings, you may be missing additional steps

http://mastykarz.nl/blog/images/ActivatingselectedFeaturesduringthedeplo_9723/deploymentconfiguration.png

Comment: Thanks Tiago. Thanks for the steps. I have already tried few but will go through all of them.